# Best way to pack data and then hash it, both in Rust and NodeJS

Tags: anchor, rust, node.js, hashing

I'm coming from Ethereum, and in Solidity we can pack data then hash it like `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(typed_data1, typed_data2, ....))`, and there is a corresponding approach in nodejs `ethers.utils.keccak256(ethers.utils.solidityPack(types, values))`.

Using this, the hash of the off-chain data can be signed, then submitted to a smart contract for verification.

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this in Solana and am having trouble finding resources. I was looking at `anchor_lang::solana_program::keccak::hashv` but this seems to be limited to arrays of u8 data, whereas I need to pack any sequence of data types.

Any tips and suggestions appreciated.

Edit:

Thanks to @arowana, I've manage to hash arbitary data using the following:

```
        #[derive(BorshSerialize)]
        struct OffChainData {
          a: u8,
          b: u64
        }
    let data = OffChainData { a: 1, b: 100213123 };
    let serialized_data: Vec<u8> = data.try_to_vec()?;
    let hash = anchor_lang::solana_program::keccak::hash(&serialized_data[..]);
    
    msg!("keccak::hash {:?}", hash);
```

My concern now is that the hash doesn't appear to be keccak-256, at least as I am used to seeing it (I would expect the above hash to be `0xa2bd9883818ee366d2793fc267127e1b2b6df28041c8a0d65fdaab5928e4d26e`). However, the above code is giving the following as a result: `Fg3EvJQ1r2FiKr7ReRUAFmn35LPGy1dVrmgVJCtf2h5B`

My remaining question is how to get this result in nodejs, ideally via `@project-serum/anchor`

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as solidity, you need to encode the data structure first, then only you can hash it. So once encoded to bytes you can use `solana_program::keccak::hashv` on the slice of bytes.

To pack data there is no solana strong standard but anchor is using the borsh crate https://crates.io/crates/borsh

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize]
struct SomeStuff {
  a: u8,
  b: u64
}
let data = SomeStuff { a: 1, b: 100213123 };
```

so if your data structure implements `BorshSerialize` (usually with the derive macro), you can serialize it with `let serialized_data: Vec<u8> = data.try_to_vec()?` then provide the slice &serialized_data to the hashv function.

Comment: I've updated my post with new info after trying your suggestions. My remaining question is how to achieve this with nodejs. I also am unfamiliar with the encoding that is being used by Solana. `Fg3EvJQ1r2FiKr7ReRUAFmn35LPGy1dVrmgVJCtf2h5B` doesn't seem like a hash I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

solana web3 is using @noble/hashes
see https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/27630

Nodejs:

```
import { keccak_256 } from '@noble/hashes/sha3';

const secret = "YourSuperSecretString";
const hashedUint8Array = keccak_256(Buffer.from(secret))
```

Rust:

```
let secret = "YourSuperSecretString".to_string();
let secret_bytes = secret.as_bytes();
let res = anchor_lang::solana_program::keccak::hash(&secret_bytes);
let hash_bytes = res.to_bytes();
```